# Radio button cannot be unchecked

Tags: android, radio-button

I have created a `radio button` in my app. Now when `radio button` isChecked I call a function, and it's working fine. But my problem is that once I checked the `radio button` then and again click of that `radio button` doesn't make it unchecked.

So, how that can be done?

My code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_frm);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(rb1.isChecked() == true)
                t1.setText("Selected is : "+rb1.getText());
            if(rb1.isChecked() == false)
                t1.setText("Selected is : ");
        }
    });

    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a radio button. Go for CheckBox. 
[Try this](http://mgmblog.com/2008/02/18/android-checkbox-oncheckedchangelistener/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use boolean Flag option ..here is the code

```
boolean flag = false;

rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(flag){

                    rb.setChecked(false);
                    flag = false;
                }
                else{

                    rb.setChecked(true);
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: yeh its working but for two times..means when i click on radiobutton it is checked again when i click on radiobutton it is unchecked so its fine but when i again click on radio button its not checked..so repeatation is not working..so how to solve it